# Is there with micronaut a way to have the "Spring Data JPA" repository autogenerated from an interface like in spring?

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, repository-pattern, micronaut

Im setting up a new micro service with micronaut and want it to access a database over jpa/hibernate.

Is there an easy way to have the "Spring Data JPA" repositories implementation to be autogenerated from the interface like with spring?

```
interface ExampleRepository {
    fun FindById(id: String): Example
}
```

Ideally i would the be able to import an ExampleRepository over DI into my service.

EDIT: Micronaut Data is in the process of being released: https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not currently, although such a feature is planned for the future.

Answer (score 1):

In July 2019 Micronaut authors released Predator — short for Precomputed Data Repositories — that is equivalent to Spring Data.

[Quoting](https://objectcomputing.com/news/2019/07/18/unleashing-predator-precomputed-data-repositories):

> Predator uses Micronaut's ahead-of-time (AoT) compilation APIs to move the entity meta-model into your compiler and translate a finder expression like findByTitle into the appropriate SQL or JPA-QL query at compilation time. A very thin runtime layer that uses Micronaut's reflection-free compilation-time AOP then only has to execute the query and return the results.

UPDATE: The project has now been renamed to "Micronaut Data", [here is the new link to the docs](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/latest/guide/)

Comment: Following the project closely and will update here when its released.